# Get numbers, a given number of characters after a phrase, from HTML

Tags: html, perl

Basically, I've opened an HTML file in perl, and wrote this line:

```
if(INFILE =~ \$txt_TeamNumber\) {
    $teamNumber = \$txt_TeamNumber\
}
```

and I need to get the txt_TeamNumber, go 21 spaces forward, and get the next 1-5 numbers. Here is the part of the HTML file I'm trying to extract info from:

```
<td style="width: 25%;">Team Number:
                </td>
                <td style="width: 75%;">
                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txt_TeamNumber" type="text" value="186" maxlength="5" readonly="readonly" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_TeamNumber" disabled="disabled" tabindex="1" class="aspNetDisabled" style="width:53px;">
                </td>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get 100 or 186?

Comment: I'm trying to get the value (186)

Comment: @AbhiNickz Please don't change the formatting of the raw data in questions unless you're sure it won't change the solutions. Even whitespace can make a difference when parsing things.

Comment: That code doesn't even compile. For a start, the slashes in your regex match are the wrong way round. Please don't retype code into your question. It's better for everyone if you cut and paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very good example for benefits of using ready parsers.

One of the standard modules for parsing HTML is [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/~cjm/HTML-Tree-5.03/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm).  Its effectiveness is to a good extent based on its good use of [HTML::Element](http://search.cpan.org/~cjm/HTML-Tree-5.03/lib/HTML/Element.pm) so always have that page ready for reference.

The question doesn't say where HTML comes from. For testing I put it in a file, wrapped with needed tags, and load it from that file. I expect it to  come from internet, please change accordingly.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Path::Tiny;    
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $file = "snippet.html";
my $html = path($file)->slurp;  # or open and slurp by hand

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html);

my @nodes = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'input');

foreach my $node (@nodes) {
    my $val = $node->look_down('name', qr/\$txt_TeamNumber/)->attr('value');
    print "'value': $val\n";
}
```

This prints the line: `'value': 186`.   Note that we never have to parse anything at all.

I assume that the `'name'` attribute is identified by *literal* `$txt_TeamNumber`, thus `$` is escaped.

The code uses the excellent [Path::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Path-Tiny-0.104/lib/Path/Tiny.pm) to `slurp` the file. If there are issues with installing a module just read the file by hand into a string (if it does come from a file and not from internet).

See docs and abundant other examples for the full utility of the `HTML` parsing modules used above.  There are of course other ways and approaches, made ready for use by yet other good modules. Please search for the right tool.

I strongly suggest to *stay clear* of any idea to parse HTML (or anything similar) with regex.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! Also, would you mind explaining to me the foreach statement? And/or anything else I might need to change in order to do the same thing with another variable? Basically, I'll need to do this same thing with another dozen variables in the same HTML file. Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: @Ultracrepidarian  Great, glad that it helps :)  So, I will add a short commentary on what this is about.  But I suggest that you find some light tutorials/examples of use of `HTML::TreeBuilder` (I can't quite write _that_ here).  I'll look and add links as well.

Comment: @Ultracrepidarian  In a nutshell: The `look_down` returns a list of "_nodes_" that it found based on its arguments, in this case of all nodes that are `input` HTML tag. Then `foreach` goes through one node at a time. Inside the loop we `look_down` further in each node, find the given `name` and pick up the `value`.  Pretty simple really.  In order to change it you need to know what you are looking for and where it is in the HTML tree. If it's just a different `name` then you can literally just change that.  Read up on the structure of an HTML document, if needed. I'll update and let you know.

Comment: I've solved this problem, but encountered another. I've made a new thread for it at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43007974/treebuilder-get-embedded-nodes . Thanks! @zdim

Comment: @Ultracrepidarian  Alright, I see that.  This is common, to have follow up problems and questions as you work further on your task.  Note though that _this answer_ deals with _this question_.  You were right to post the other one separately as it is a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Watch for variable scoping. You should be able to get it with a simple regexp capture:

```
if(INFILE =~ /$txt_TeamNumber/) {
    $teamNumber = /$txt_TeamNumber/
    ($value) = /$txt_TeamNumber.*?value="(.*?)"/
}
```

Comment: I haven't had the chance to test this yet, but thank you! Could you by chance explain what this code snippet does exactly? I will need to write about 20 more of these for different info I need to extract, and I'd love to know exactly what it does! Thanks!

Comment: It works similar to your original match, however anything in parenthesis is captured. A period is a wild card for any character. An asterisk is 0 or more of the previous character and a question mark enforces stringent matching, meaning it will match the least possible characters. The captured part then gets fed into the variable $value. For  strict code you want to instantiate your variables with `my` at some point, but you probably want to do that outside your loop, before your if statement. `my ($teamNumber, $value);`