# TreeBuilder Get embedded nodes

Tags: html, perl, module, html-treebuilder

Basically, I need to get the names and emails from all of these people in the HTML code.

```
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="rgHeader" style="text-align:center;">Name</th><th scope="col" class="rgHeader" style="text-align:center;">Email Address</th><th scope="col" class="rgHeader" style="text-align:center;">School Phone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead><tbody>
    <tr class="rgRow" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rg_People_ctl00__0">
        <td>
                            Michael Bowen
                        </td><td>mbowen@cpcisd.net</td><td>903-488-3671 ext3200</td>
    </tr><tr class="rgAltRow" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rg_People_ctl00__1">
        <td>
                            Christian Calixto
                        </td><td>calixtoc@cpcisd.net</td><td>903-488-3671 x 3430</td>
    </tr><tr class="rgRow" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rg_People_ctl00__2">
        <td>
                            Rachel Claxton
                        </td><td>claxtonr@cpcisd.net</td><td>903-488-3671 x 3450</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

</table><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rg_People_ClientState" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rg_People_ClientState" type="hidden" autocomplete="off">    </div>


        <br>
```

I know how to use treebuilder with the nodes and such, and I'm using this code in some of my script.

```
    my ($file) = @_;
my $html = path($file)-> slurp;
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html);
my @nodes = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'input');
my $val;
foreach my $node (@nodes) {
    $val = $node->look_down('name', qr/\$txt_Website/)->attr('value');
}
return $val;
```

I was going to use the same code for this function, but I realized that I don't have much to search for, since the `<td>` tag is in so many other places in the script. I'm sure there's a better way to approach this problem, but I can't seem to find it.

LINK TO HTML CODE: http://pastebin.com/qLwu80ZW

MY CODE: https://pastebin.com/wGb0eXmM

Note: I did look on google as much as possible, but I'm not quite sure what I should search for.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? As far as I can see, you just want the first two `td` elements inside each `tr`.

Comment: @Borodin Precisely. I just have no idea how I would approach that. I've tried my best to look at tutorials on TreeBuilder, but still can't figure it out. Sorry and, Thanks!

Comment: Well you already do it with `input` elements. Just use `td` and `tr` instead.

Comment: @Borodin I would, but there are multiple `td` and `tr` tags in the code. I just shared a clip of it. Thank you for the fast help, dude!

Comment: @Borodin Should I link to the whole html code?+

Comment: We can't help you to exclude the parts you don't want unless we can see it. Is the `class="rgHeader"` unique perhaps? Or you can just pick the Nth table in the page.

Comment: Yes, I think you will have to.

Comment: @Borodin Alright. I've edited the thread.

Comment: It seems that in this document the `rgRow` in `<tr class="rgRow"` gets you to the place you need. So that can be the first `look_down`, giving you the right rows of the (right) table. Then, in each such node look for `td` tags and get their values (name, email, phone).  OR, you can pick the table number 2 and use the excellent  [HTML::TableExtract](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-TableExtract/lib/HTML/TableExtract.pm), in which case you don't need the to use the `TreeBuilder`, for this particular task.  (I can post this later, if you don't manage or if no one else does.)

Comment: Just noticed that one of the three is `<tr class="rgAltRow"`, so the class name is different.  If this implies some functional difference you can search for it separately.  If not, construct the regex to match either `rgRow` or `rgAltRow` so to get all nodes with this info. In this document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `table` element that encloses the data you need has a unique class `rgMasterTable` so you can search for that in `look_down`

I've written this to demonstrate. It pulls the HTML directly from your pastebin

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use LWP::Simple 'get';
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

use constant URL => 'http://pastebin.com/raw/qLwu80ZW';

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content(get URL);

my ($table) = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'table', class => 'rgMasterTable');

for my $tr ( $table->look_down(_tag => 'tr') ) {

    next unless my @td = $tr->look_down(_tag => 'td');

    my ($name, $email) = map { $_->as_trimmed_text } @td[0,1];

    printf  "%-17s %s\n", $name, $email;
}
```

#### output

```
Michael Bowen     mbowen@cpcisd.net
Christian Calixto calixtoc@cpcisd.net
Rachel Claxton    claxtonr@cpcisd.net
```

Comment: Absolutely stupendous! Not all heroes wear capes ;D

Comment: I've just uncovered an error. When I try to run the script, I get an error on your snippet of code. I feel like it could be something to do with what @zdim said above:

" 
Just noticed that one of the three is <tr class="rgAltRow", so the class name is different. If this implies some functional difference you can search for it separately. If not, construct the regex to match either rgRow or rgAltRow so to get all nodes with this info. In this document" 

Also, my error is this:
`Can't call method "look_down" on an unidentified value at spreadsheet.pl line 174`

Thank you both!

Comment: @Ultracrepidarian: My solution works with the data you have published. The class of the `tr` elements is irrelevant. I can't debug your code without seeing it, and it needs to be another question if you can't fix it yourself. Basically you're calling `look_down` on something without checking whether the previous search succeeded; the only place my code does that is looking for the initial `table` element.

Comment: @Ultracrepidarian: What have you changed from my code?

Comment: @Ultracrepidarian  As for my comment you quote, Borodin is using `rgMasterTable` (class) from the `<table>` itself, and then searches for the `<tr>` and then `<td>` elements (tags). So this code doesn't depend on `rgRow|rgAltRow` (or whatever the class name of `td` may be).  You must have changed something in this code so look carefully through all of it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, zdim. @Borodin I've changed a few things. I've updated my thread to have a link to my full code. The part I'm having trouble with is line 169 to 179.

Comment: I've fixed that error by just extracting the file directly from the pastebin, as @Borodin did. But now I'm getting another error saying `Error open (<) on '1.html': No such file or directory at spreadsheet.pl line 18.` I have no idea why it might be saying this, or even where to start.

Comment: @Ultracrepidarian: You're raising new issues now, and you need to open a new question.